# Starring a message in chat that has a tag late in the message causes an empty tag box in the star list

Tags: bug, tags, chat, markdown, chat-stars

Well, that's a decent title. Now what the heck am I talking about?

> [image: Empty tag box in star list]
> <sub>Caused by starring [this chat message](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/7966220#7966220).</sub>

Seems to me like the box shouldn't be there at all since the tag is not part of the shortened blurb. It functions like a normal tag, with the hover effect and everything, and actually links to the [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) tag - the text has just been removed from it.

Comment: This seems related to the borkification of unicode characters late in the message.